# Condicionar las respuestas según la cantidad y eliminar las mismas formulario de google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Tengo [el siguiente formulario](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/106mg3Tb2YHxdn8GwdBO6nmrGsT2UyIQGnLS7oBLOnsA/edit) donde la persona selecciona diferentes opciones 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. Estas opciones tienen una cuota de selección. Es decir, por ejemplo, la opción 1 se puede solo elegir 5 veces. Esta información está en [este sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16E1iRfRWQ82rqIWy5s4PXBfbvUn2prVV8p06nHKFyAA/edit#gid=1872966494) en la hoja datos. Este sheet es el vinculado con el form en la primera pestaña recibe la información y en la tabla de la hoja datos cuenta la cantidad de anotados en cada opción.

Digamos que jugando con chatgpt me tiro este código el cual pegue en el formulario y agregue a un activador para que se ejecute al enviar un formulario. Pero no hay caso cuando la cantidad de anotados supera el cupo sigue mostrando la opción que supero este criterio y no la elimina que sería el objetivo.

Dejo el código por acá y cualquiera que me pueda dar una mano se lo agradeceria.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // Obtén el ID del formulario.
  var formId = e.source.formId;

  // Obtén el ID de la hoja de datos.
  var sheetId = "16E1iRfRWQ82rqIWy5s4PXBfbvUn2prVV8p06nHKFyAA";

  // Obtén el rango de celdas donde se almacenan los datos.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName("datos");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C5");

  // Obtén la opción seleccionada del formulario.
  var selectedOption = e.namedValues["opción_seleccionada"];

  // Obtén el taller, el cupo y la cantidad de anotados.
  var [taller, cupo, cantidadDeAnotados] = range.getValues()[0];

  // Busca la opción seleccionada en el rango de celdas.
  var optionIndex = range.find(selectedOption);

  // Si la opción seleccionada se encuentra en el rango de celdas, elimina la opción.
  if (optionIndex !== -1) {
    var form = FormApp.openById(formId);
    var question = form.getQuestionById("opción_seleccionada");
    question.removeOption(optionIndex);
    form.save();
  }
}
```